# Can moral truths be known a priori or are they based on experience?

Tags: ethics, epistemology, knowledge, empiricism

I am currently working on an essay that explores the concept of a priori knowledge and whether or not it can exist. I would love to hear any thoughts or opinions on this topic that anyone may have.

From my understanding, a priori knowledge is knowledge that can be known independently of experience or empirical evidence. It is often contrasted with a posteriori knowledge, which is knowledge that can only be known through experience or observation.

My initial thought is that a priori knowledge may exist in certain cases, such as in mathematics or logical reasoning. For example, the statement "2+2=4" can be known without any empirical evidence or experience, and is therefore a priori knowledge. However, I am unsure if this applies to other areas of knowledge, such as ethics or metaphysics.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or perspectives on this topic that anyone may have. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: See [A Priorism in Moral Epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-epistemology-a-priori/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. Would you say there are other good examples of a priori knowledge?

Comment: Morals are socially defined rules (if my group tells that it is bad to eat chicken, I must not; and if I do it, it is evidently an immoral act, even I I think it's moral: it is the group that determines moral rules). Therefore they are empirical knowledge. Therefore, _a posteriori_.

Comment: As another perspective, I would argue that a priori knowledge gives an individual an evolutionary advantage over an individual without it. The more knowledge you are born with, the better your chances of success. Yet it seems that humans are born mostly blank. A priori knowledge is a detriment under a constantly changing world. Better to be flexible.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Yes, more capability with less inborn requires a longer training period. I often wonder if modern culture will eventually require more preparation time than people can spare in learning it? Then society would fragment into specialist areas... Maybe it's already happened? We outdeveloped our intelligence?

Comment: @ScottRowe We live in an unprecedented age of  instantly available information which favors development without any a priori information. I believe as a society, we are still on a steep learning curve when it comes to an individuals ability to sift through all that data. I do believe being born with antiquated knowledge is worse than being born with none at all.